# Wireless Problem on Acer Aspire 5610z

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my machine, but I can't get wireless connection to work. My computer is Acer Aspire 5610z. I found that some other people that have same computer, face the same problem.

Here is some information about it:

******** *info trace* **********

* uname -a ***

Linux ucy-Aspire-5610Z 3.8.0-32-generic #47~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 16:22:28 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

* lsb_release ***

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

* lspci ***

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. Device [1468:0422]

### Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

06:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0090]
    Kernel driver in use: b44

* lsusb ***

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:0100 Acer, Inc Orbicam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Wireless Mouse M305
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

* PCMCIA Card Info ***

PRODID_1=""
PRODID_2=""
PRODID_3=""
PRODID_4=""
MANFID=0000,0000
FUNCID=255

* iwconfig ***

* rfkill ***

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

* lsmod ***

ssb_hcd                12781  0 
ssb                    51554  2 ssb_hcd,b44

* nm-tool ***

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: usb0  [Wired connection 2] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            rndis_host
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:

  Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
  Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         192.168.42.7
  Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
  Gateway:         192.168.42.129

  DNS:             192.168.42.129

  IPv6 Settings:
  Address:         ::a05d:a1ff:fea4:1738
  Prefix:          64
  Gateway:         fe80::504d:76ff:fe86:db04

  Address:         fe80::a05d:a1ff:fea4:1738
  Prefix:          64
  Gateway:         fe80::504d:76ff:fe86:db04

  DNS:             fe80::504d:76ff:fe86:db04
- Device: eth2 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            b44
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:

  Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
  Carrier:         off

* NetworkManager.state ***

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

* NetworkManager.conf ***

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

* interfaces ***

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

* iwlist ***

* resolv.conf ***

nameserver 127.0.0.1

* blacklist ***

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

* modinfo ***

filename:       /lib/modules/3.8.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/host/ssb-hcd.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Common USB driver for SSB Bus
author:         Hauke Mehrtens
srcversion:     E127A51EDC8F44D2C2A8F15
alias:          ssb:v4243id0819rev*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0817rev*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0808rev*
depends:        ssb
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.8.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686

filename:       /lib/modules/3.8.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     14621F6EC014F731244437C
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004350sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004329sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004325sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004324sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004322sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004321sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004320sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004319sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014A4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004315sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004312sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004311sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004307sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004306sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004301sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.8.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686

* udev rules ***

## PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:06:01.0/ssb1:0 (b44)

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

## PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:06:01.0/ssb2:0 (b44)

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

## PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:06:01.0/ssb3:0 (b44)

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"

* dmesg ***

[    2.385241] ssb: Found chip with id 0x4311, rev 0x01 and package 0x00
[    2.385256] ssb: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (cc 0x800, rev 0x11, vendor 0x4243)
[    2.385266] ssb: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (cc 0x812, rev 0x0A, vendor 0x4243)
[    2.385276] ssb: Core 2 found: USB 1.1 Host (cc 0x817, rev 0x03, vendor 0x4243)
[    2.385286] ssb: Core 3 found: PCI-E (cc 0x820, rev 0x01, vendor 0x4243)
[    2.448147] ssb: Sonics Silicon Backplane found on PCI device 0000:05:00.0
[    2.468112] ssb: Found chip with id 0x4401, rev 0x02 and package 0x00
[    2.468124] ssb: Core 0 found: Fast Ethernet (cc 0x806, rev 0x07, vendor 0x4243)
[    2.468132] ssb: Core 1 found: V90 (cc 0x807, rev 0x03, vendor 0x4243)
[    2.468140] ssb: Core 2 found: PCI (cc 0x804, rev 0x0A, vendor 0x4243)
[    2.508230] ssb: Sonics Silicon Backplane found on PCI device 0000:06:01.0
[    2.528620] b44 ssb1:0 eth0: Broadcom 44xx/47xx 10/100 PCI ethernet driver

************ done ******************

Thank you already for your help.

Comment: Could u post what u tried so far, what exactly is your issue. Could you post output of `sudo lspci -v` and `ifconfig`, and did u install any additional drivers for your card?

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: I did what you told me and also I pasted in my post. Here is the link: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6304681/ And thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please post the output of lspci -vnn | grep -i Net -A 12   Ty

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

You have the appropriate driver for your card, b43, blacklisted. Normally, this is a consequence of having the proprietary driver, wl, installed. So, my suggestion is to remove first thing the proprietary driver,

```
 sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and then to install the necessary firmware,

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and eventually to load your open source module:

```
sudo rmmod b43
sudo modprobe b43
```